# How to label parameters in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, core-language, labeling

How do I label the "2" and "3" so they show "square" and "cubed" in Manipulate controls? The following is my code:

```
f[x_] := x
Manipulate[f[x]^n, {x, -10, 10, 1}, {n, {2, 3}}]
```

Comment: You find this information in the documentation page of `Manipulate`. Open the "Details and Options` section and it should jump right at you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
Manipulate[
  x^n,
  {x, -10, 10, 1, Appearance-> "Labeled"},
  {{n, 2}, {2 -> "square", 3 -> "cube"}}]
```

[image: manip]

Comment: in the {{n, 2}, {...}} what does the 2 do?

Comment: @JulesManson. It sets the initial value for the setter bar.